# Why should PyImport_AppendInittab() be called before Py_Initialize()?

Tags: c++, python

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_AppendInittab), PyImport_AppendInittab "should be called before Py_Initialize()."

There is no explanation of why this is the case, and ignoring this advice yields a working application. So, since this is working, under what circumstances will it not work?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827185/how-can-pyimport-appendinittab-fail

Comment: Thanks Simon, I already saw that question, but it didn't really answer my question. I'd rather hear something like "because the probability of getting an out of memory exception will be lower when calling it before than after calling Py_Initialize (so that you get an out of memory error when calling Py_Initialize)", which then tells me that "it's ok to do it, but that it just may fail" because of the memory (and name clashes). I'm afraid that it could be some serious issue like pointers getting messed up which then make hell break loose in a very subtle way, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the documentation says so; and violating the API might yield a working application today but not tomorrow.

A couple of issues you might encounter:

- `sys.builtin_module_names` is initialized within `Py_Initialize`, so it won't contain your module
- `PyImport_AppendInittab` does not take any locks, so if you call it after `Py_Initialize` in a multithreaded application you could get memory corruption

Comment: Well yes, the issue is to be in the know of when one is violating the API. If we go after RFC 2119, I can assume that it is possible to invert the order without having any issues at all, as long as the implications are well understood. The 2 points you mention are interesting, but 1) wherein lies the benefit of having a module as a built-in? 2) is it possible to add a boost::python module optionally at runtime, at any point in the program execution, without the need of PyImport_AppendInittab or doing an exec("import imp\n"...) in Python? Where did you get those 2 points from, experience? Thnx

Comment: @DanielF. 1) The point of having a module as a built-in is that it can expose functionality of your embedding application. 2) The only reason to add a module is in response to an import, so you should be adding hooks to the import mechanism rather than abusing `PyImport_AppendInittab `. 3) Experience and http://hg.python.org

Comment: Regarding 1) I was also able to use the module when calling PyImport_AppendInittab after Py_Initialize. The only apparent difference was that it didn't appear in sys.builtin_module_names. Regardless of that, printing out the module gave <module 'my_module' (built-in)> in both cases.

Comment: Due the documentation do not point to the alternative method to register embedded modules after PyInitialize, can someone give a brief link or description of what method to use, so I can submit a PR to the documentation?